In Playwright, How to know if you're in headless mode during runtime?
When you're developing E2E tests and running in headed mode, you can skip some steps (like login) to save time or add some info only in debug mode.
I've looked for a property in the documentation and in other questions but there is no answer.

I would rather use the testInfo property:
test('Only in hedless', async ({ page }, testInfo) => {
    test.fixme(!testInfo.project.use.headless, 'Only works in headless mode');
});


It will work only when use.headless is set - not the actual state of the browser

@unickq yes. And I think it won't work if you use the --headed flag. But it's better than getting to an internal variable.

Why is it better than getting an internal variable?

@unickq because they can change that variable name whenever they want.

Just get it from browser properties.
import { test } from "@playwright/test";

test("from browser", async ({ browser }) => {
  console.log(browser["_options"].headless);
});

test("from page", async ({ page }) => {
  const browser = page.context().browser()!;
  console.log(browser["_options"].headless);
});


Works for use: { headless: boolean } in playwright config. And --headed playwright test param.

Is that browser option reflects the actual state of the browser? or being set internally by playwright corresponding to configuration?

It's a state of the browser. Headless flag is part of use config and it's public

Disclaimer: This isn't guaranteed to continue working in next versions (>"@playwright/test": "1.44.1") as it's using private parameters. But it will give the actual state of the browser regardless of how you chose it's head mode.
function isHeadless(browser) {
  return browser._browserType._defaultLaunchOptions.headless
}

Of course, this requires to get the browser param. I've used the setup method setup("Your setup...", async ({ browser }) => { to do this.
This works on chromium and firefox as far as I've tested.
[Optional robustness addition]
public static safeAssign<T>(expression: () => T, defaultValue: T): T {
    try {
      return expression();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('An error occurred during safeAssign:', error);
      return defaultValue;
    }
  }

const isHeadless = Utils.safeAssign(() => (browser as any)._browserType._defaultLaunchOptions.headless, null);

Hope this will help someone.
